# Change Text During Load Of Header Tag

Tags: html, cordova, innerhtml

I'm having a problem with my PhoneGap application. I have a page with a header tag.
I want to change the innerHTML of that header when it's loaded.

My header does not contain an id and I want this task done without having additional id's or classes because my header is part of automatically generated code. I would have to create an algorithm to generate id's.

I want to decide the display text of the header during the load of that header tag. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Greets,

You can simply do:

- Using `jQuery`:

  ```
  $('header').append('<somethin />');
  ```
- Using `JavaScript`:

  ```
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( ... );
  ```

---

If you're talking about `jquery-mobile` header divs, You can do it like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('div[data-role=header]').html('yourhtml');
    $('div[data-role=page]').trigger("pagecreate");
});
```

or just:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('div[data-role=header]').html('yourhtml').trigger("pagecreate");
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2bLM6/3/

I used `$( document ).ready()` there, but u can choose whatever event u wish, the `.trigger("pagecreate")` will do the "refresh" job =)